# Can not find Karma when installed on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, karma-runner, npm-install

I installed visual studio 2015.

Then I run the `npm.cmd` command (which is installed when installing Visual Studio) (in a `cmd` window which I started as administrator) to install `karma` with these commands:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\npm.cmd" install -g karma
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\npm.cmd" install -g karma-cli
```

I understood that this will install Karma globally, so I can run it from anywhere.

But when I try to run karma (even when I am in the folder I was when I ran the npm commands), I get the `'karma' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` message.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not get it to work with the Node version which was installed with Visual Studio.

Node, as installed with Visual Studio, is a sort of, I don't know how to call it, 'side install' or 'embedded install'. It's not the real NodeJs I guess and it's installed in the Visual Studio directories. (I also do knot know how it gets updated and how security updates are made).

I ended up installing the 'normal' NodeJs which worked instantly.
All the paths were setup correct so when I installed NodeJs, I could run `npm` from every folder and when I ran the Karma installs I could also start the Karma from every location.

So I stopped looking for the solution with the 'with Visual Studio preinstalled version' and ended up working with the 'normal NodeJs'.